# Does anyone have a working example of ParticleExplosion in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to iPhone development and I'd really like to see a working example of this particular effect. Thanks in advance.

[ParticleExplosion](http://www.sapusmedia.com/cocos2d-iphone-api-doc/interface_particle_explosion.html)

Comment: It'd be great to see implementations of any of the effects actually, e.g. ParticleFire, ParticleFireworks, ParticleFlower, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you open up Cocos2d source code in Xcode, you should be able to launch the ParticleTest example that contains all of particle effects. Alternatively, search youtube for cocos2d, there's a demo video that shows all of these effects.

Answer (score 2):

```
    CCParticleSystem *emitter = [CCParticleExplosion node];

    //set the location of the emitter
    emitter.position = mySprite.position;

    //set size of particle animation
    emitter.scale = 0.5;

    //set an Image for the particle
    emitter.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"particle.png"];

    //set length of particle animation
    [emitter setLife:0.5f];

    //add to layer ofcourse(effect begins after this step)
    [self addChild: emitter];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

ParticleSystem *emitter = [ParticleExplosion node];
[self addChild: emitter];

Comment: Do I put that in init? It says it's undeclared. Is there a more detailed explanation?